# ERROR: table name "va_user_feedback" specified more than once

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have the below SQL:

```
UPDATE va_user_feedback
SET cust_first_name = va_customer.cust_first_name
FROM va_customer
JOIN va_user_feedback
ON va_customer.user_profile_id = va_user_feedback.created_by_user_id;
```

I am receiving the below error:

> ERROR: table name "va_user_feedback" specified more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat the target table in the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE va_user_feedback
  SET cust_first_name = va_customer.cust_first_name
FROM va_customer
WHERE va_customer.user_profile_id = va_user_feedback.created_by_user_id;
```